# Make the input_URL an array that will have multiple URLs inside

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, windows

In the code u can see a var called input_URL, to the variable at line 44 is a value attached in which the user inputs an url, and then the input_URL is used in line 112 to open a new tab. The problem is that i want to have multiple url in that variable because i want the user to be able to store multiple URLs and open them at whenever time he wants. I tried doing it with arrays but i couldn't figure it out, i get to the part where i can store more urls in the same array but do not know how would i access them in line 112(each one at certain time)
I added the html script as well if you want to try the script.

```
//variables
        var button1;
        var text;
        var button2;
        var buttonPlus;

        var breaks;

        var input_URL;



        var ids1 = 0;
        var input_value;
        var choose_title;
        //variables

        function addURL() 
        {

            ids1++;
            document.getElementById('firstButton').onclick='';

            text = document.createElement('SPAN');

            button1 = document.createElement('SPAN');

            breaks = document.createElement('BR');

            text.innerHTML='<input id="input" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:2px" type="text" input type="reset" autocomplete="off" onclick="input.value = null " value="Enter URL" <br/>';



            button1.innerHTML='<input id="okButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="getInput()" value="OK" <br/>';

            document.body.append(text);
            document.body.append(button1);
            document.body.append(breaks);

        }

        function getInput()
        {
           choose_title = prompt("Choose a title for your URL");

++++++++LINE 44      input_URL = document.getElementById('input').value;



             if(choose_title == "")
                {
                    window.alert("PLEASE ENTER A TITLE");
                    getInput();
                }

            else if(choose_title == null){
                return;
            }

            else{



            //delete Elements
            text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
            button1.parentNode.removeChild(button1);

            var del3 = document.getElementById('firstButton');
            del3.parentNode.removeChild(del3);


            breaks.parentNode.removeChild(breaks);
            //delete Elements

            var del3 = document.getElementById('firstSpan');
            del3.parentNode.removeChild(del3)

            button2 = document.createElement('SPAN');
            document.body.append(button2); 
            button2.innerHTML='<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin:2px" onclick="OpenInNewTab()" id="btn2">';



            ids++;

            document.getElementById('btn2').id = ids;

            document.getElementById(ids).setAttribute('value',choose_title);


            document.body.append(breaks);

            buttonPlus = document.createElement('SPAN');
            buttonPlus.id = 'firstSpan';
            buttonPlus.innerHTML = '<input id="firstButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:2px" type="button" onclick="addURL()" value="+" <br/>';
            document.body.append(buttonPlus);

            }




            //Save input_value & title to computer


        }


        function OpenInNewTab()
        {
+++++++++LINE 112  link=window.open(input_URL, '_blank');
            //link.focus();
        }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" integrity="sha384-      ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Warper</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:rgb(230, 255, 255)">

    <h1 class="display-1" style="color:aqua; font-size:90px; text-align:center; ">WARPER</h1>
    <p class="h6" style="text-align:center">Warp to anywhere you desire.</p>
    <span id="firstSpan">
    <input id="firstButton" style="margin:2px " class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addURL()"value="+">
    </span>


<script src="Script1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to open all URLs of the array at once?

Comment: no i as u can see the function OpenInNewTab() is ran when the user presses the button. There are more buttons, and each should link to another url from the array

Comment: u can test the code just put it in a .html file and add a button with id(firstButton)

Comment: i changed the question little bit there was a mistake